# Changing html element's position in parent tag when created it with document.createElement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just starting learning Javascript, and right now I'm on `document.createElement`. I understood that you can create a HTML tag this way, and that afterwards you have to put it into a HTML tag that already exists (parent). My question is **Can I choose exactly where I put this created HTML tag in the parent tag ?**

Let's say for exemple I have the following HTML :

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
  <p>Third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And this javascript :

```
const getMyDiv = document.getElementById("parent");
const createParagraph = document.createElement("p");
getMyDiv.appendChild(createParagraph);
```

I will have the following result :

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
  <p>Third paragraph</p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

So what i'm asking is how can I create this `<p>` at a different position, for exemple like this :

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.appendChild()`, indeed append your created element at the end of the list of the children of your selected element, as you demonstrated.

Though, there are other methods that can be used, based on your needs, so you can mount your element wherever you want e.g. [.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) or [.prepend()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

There are some differences on how they work, so I suggest you take a look on the provided links so you can understand the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script if you want to place the

position to a specific location

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
<script language="javascript">
function myFunction(){
    //var getMyDiv = document.getElementById("parent");
    //var createParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    //getMyDiv.appendChild(createParagraph);

    var child = document.createElement('p')
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    parent.insertChildAtIndex(child, 2)
}


Element.prototype.insertChildAtIndex = function(child, index) {

    if (!index) index = 0
    if (index >= this.children.length) {

        this.appendChild(child)
    } else {

        this.insertBefore(child, this.children[index])
    }
}
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="parent" style="background-color:red;width=100px;height:100px">
  <div>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
  <p>Third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

to check save as html file and look at the inspection element in the browser

Comment: Thank you, this gives me another useful way to do it, appreciate your help !